# Stacked bar chart showing row labels above other labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, bar-chart, react-chartjs-2

I am build a chart where the rows are the assignees' names
and when I have too many assignees the chart just put one name above other (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNk5A.png). I want to just add space between the names so they can be read.

[image: image of the chart with to many assignees]

This is my chart component

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { Bar, getElementsAtEvent } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { type StackedChartProps } from "next/types";
import Loading from "../loading";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const options = {
  indexAxis: "y" as const,
  plugins: {},
  resposive: true,
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
      beginAtZero: true,
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false,
      },
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

type StackedBarProps = StackedChartProps;

export default function StackedBarChart({
  onClick,
  width,
  height,
  isLoading,
  level,
  data,
}: StackedBarProps) {
  const ref = useRef<ChartJS<"bar", any, any> | null>(null);

  const handleClick = (e: any) => {
    const field =
      data.labels[getElementsAtEvent(ref.current as any, e)[0]?.index ?? 0];
    if (ref.current && onClick) onClick(field, level);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center bg-white">
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loading className={`w-[${width}] h-[${height}]`} />
      ) : (
        <Bar options={options} ref={ref} data={data} onClick={handleClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is where i calculate the chart data

```
const dataset: StackedChartData = {
      labels: assignees,
      datasets: stages.map((stage) => ({
        label: stage,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: getStatusColor(stage),
      })),
    };

    dataset.datasets.forEach((data, datasetIndex) => {
      dataset.labels.forEach((label) => {
        let count = 0;
        issues.forEach((issue) => {
          if (issue.fields.assignee?.displayName !== label) return;
          if (
            normalizeString(data.label) !==
            normalizeString(issue.fields.status.name)
          )
            return;
          count++;
        });
        dataset.datasets[datasetIndex]?.data.push(count);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Chart.js is trying its best to position them accordingly, you just have too many of them and it's impossible to do so without changing the font size. Either stop a few labels from being shown by setting them to `''`, change the font size or change the chart's scale.

Comment: how could i change the scale?

Comment: The scale of the labels (font size) or the whole chart (width/height)?